# MiKTeX trying to create PK fonts that already exist

Tags: fonts, miktex

Just as a preface: I'm still very new to Latex. So I have a package that I wrote to work on top of the base `letter` class to add some custom functionality (letterhead, fonts, formatting, etc.) On the Linux and OSX machines I've tried everything works totally fine (using pdfLaTeX or latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf), but on Windows using MiKTeX and pdfLaTeX compiling a letter with just the letterhead (which uses the font in question) fails with the output:

```
Trying to make PK font ruhvr8rc at 600 DPI...
Running miktex-makemf.exe
miktex-makemf: The ruhvr8rc source code could not be found.
Running ttf2pk.exe...
miktex-makepk: PK font ruhvr8rc could not be created.
```

I already have the file `ruhv8rc.600pk` in the MiKTeX tree (`C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9`), in the same sub-directory as it is on the other systems, and I've refreshed the file name database with and without admin privileges. On the other machines I've tried this was enough, just copying the fonts into the font directory and running

```
sudo texhash
```

or

```
sudo mktexslr
```

did the trick.

So my question is: what are the differences between the MiKTeX tree and the TeX Live (`texmf`) tree that are causing this problem?

I've read similar questions, but the most common answers all involve map files, which I do not have (and haven't needed on any other distribution). I have only `.xxxpk` files and `.tfm` files for the font causing trouble.

Comment: Using MiKTeX 2.9 and pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.11 (with pdfLaTeX format) on Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The naming/storing convention of pk-files in miktex are different. miktex will not use the extension (`600pk`) to denote the resolution but a folder. E.g. I have 600 dpi `pk` in this location:

`\fonts\pk\ljfour\jknappen\ec\dpi600\ecrm12.pk`